# Open third party Epub readers

Tags: android, filereader, epub

Actually I wanna develop a books list with EPUB format (list will be retrieved from web service).

When an item (a book) is selected, it should prompt up with available epub readers installed in the mobile. Similar to "Share" will invoke SMS, FB, Twitter etc apps.

I know there are third party EPUB reader sdk, but I don't wanna develop just another epub reader. Can someone point me to the correct resource please?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach to have a third-party app view a file is to use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, with a `Uri` pointing to the file (e.g., as published [via `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)), and the MIME type for that file (e.g., `application/epub+zip` for EPUB).

Comment: This is enough for me to catch up with the feature. Thanks to one and only @CommmonsWare